# Is it possible to get the actual object from a LockerService Proxy?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I am trying to work with an `ArrayBuffer` object in a lightning component. This `ArrayBuffer` is being created from a url via a third party library (JSZip). This is working, but with LockerService active, rather than an `ArrayBuffer` I get a `Proxy` with the properties `Proxy {$actual$: ArrayBuffer}`. If I then go to use this to create a `DataView` for example by calling `new DataView(myBuffer)`, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: First argument to DataView constructor must be an ArrayBuffer

Is there any supported way to pull the actual `ArrayBuffer` object out of that `Proxy` so that I can work with it?

**Update for XHR**

I am adding a few more details on this. It appears I can use an `ArrayBuffer` if I am constructing it myself, but when trying to get it from `XMLHttpRequest.response` I am getting back a `Proxy`. Is there a different LockerService friendly way I can get the direct `ArrayBuffer` out of the response without it being set up as a `Proxy`?

Comment: This was fixed in Winter 17 release that is making its way to all instances currently. I assume you are on an instance that is running Summer 17. If that is not the case, we will investigate.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible currently. The proxy is part of the security mechanism that was implemented.

Comment: Does this mean that `ArrayBuffer` is simply not supported? It is listed in the compatibility table (http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV#) but if it cannot be passed as an argument to any of the other constructors/functions that consume it then all I would be able to do was see the length of the buffer.

Comment: @dsharrison, `ArrayBuffer` is supported since you can do `new ArrayBuffer()". However, there are issues around proxies, in particular when a proxy is send to a method or a constructor, as in your case. I need to discuss with the implementer to understand why we need to wrap that specific type.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added a small note to my question that explains that I am pulling the ArrayBuffer out of an XMLHttpRequest reaponse. It looks like the framework is converting both ArrayBuffer and Blob response types too Proxy, which is where my issue is coming from.

Comment: @dsharrison, could you provide me with the AuraJarVersion that are you using? Can you check this link on your instance? /sfdc/releaseVersion.jsp